# Ubuntu & OpenConnect : any way to provide additional arguments?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, networkmanager, openconnect

I'm using OpenConnect to connect to my workplace via VPN. This works fine, but I'd like to use Ubuntu's network manager to establish connections. I guess it's a matter of having all connections managed by the network manager, and have connections available by a couple of clicks.

Now, the network-manager-openconnect allows me to provide a few configuration details. However, there's a great deal of options I can't provide through the UI to configure an openconnect connection. Is there a way I can control this, either through the UI or through the connection's profile file (physical file).

Examples of arguments are the --no-xmlpost and --csd-wrapper arguments.

Comment: another one (I need) is reducing MTU like `-m 1200` to fix mysterious ssh over vpn problems

Answer (score 0):

--useragent also seems important instead of individual fixes like this PR https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager-openconnect/pull/1 a general solution would be way better